# Regular Expressions: Dealing with + (Plus) Sign

Tags: regex, escaping

I am a little confused with regular expressions. My intent in below example is to replace all 'NE_*NS*+' with 'NE_*OS*+_OE_*NS*'.When I am giving below code, I don't see any issue with replace results

```
tempString1 = tempString1.replace (/\NE__NS_+/g,'NE__OS_+_OE__NS_');
```

When I am giving below code, I see that there are issues. My intent here is to replace all < mn+>  with < mn> [No space between < and m]

```
tempString2 = tempString2.replace (/\<mn>+/g,'<mn>');
```

and right code for above replace seems to be

```
tempString3 = tempString3.replace (/\<mn>\+/g,'<mn>');
```

Why is '+' not relevant in replace example of tempString1 while it is relevant in tempString2 example and wont work until I change it as per code in tempString3?

I have tough time understanding regex. Any books/articles that can help me understand them. I am a novice at regular expression.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any issue with the first one? The result of replacing "NE__NS+" using that would be "NE__OS_+_OE__NS_+" (with the plus at the end). Since your regex "NE__NS_+" would match "NE__NS" followed by "at least one underscore"

Comment: Oh I see that. Since I am performing an addition operation, that wouldn't have come as an issue when performing necessary arithmetic. So should I use tempString1.replace "(/\NE__NS_\+/g,'NE__OS_+_OE__NS_');" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

Let's take a closer look at your various regexes. You'll understand what's going on:

- **tempString1** `\NE__NS_+`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Clearly, one or more `_` are expected at the end.

- **tempString2** `\<mn>+`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The `\` is simply ignored because it is an escape character. Moreover, it used before `<` that's don't need to be escaped. Again, `>` are expected one or more times.

- **tempString3** `\<mn>\+`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Here the `+` is escaped, indicating that it is not a meta-character but the plus sign that has to be matched from your temporary string.

---

### The solution

To sum it up, if you want to match `NE_NS+`, the plus sign must be escaped.
So your regex will be:

```
NE_NS\+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

If you want to match `< mn+>`, you'll use `\s` for matching a blank character (space, tabulation, carriage return etc). Again, you must escape `+` since it's a meta character.
So, you end up with:

```
<\smn\+>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

---

### There is more...

Use the powerful [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) to **visualize** your regex.

Secondly, use [Regexr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to quickly live test your regex against a given input text.

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty helpful